IIS does not pass on REMOTE_USER with HTTP Platform Handler
I have a Django server application that I am running with IIS on Windows Server (using HTTP Platform Handler). I would like to use Windows Authentication.
I have enabled Windows Authentication in the server settings in IIS. If I understood the documentation correctly, I would expect that for each request, IIS would then send a REMOTE_USER object in the HTTP request to the Django server. However, this does not happen. REMOTE_USER is neither a server environment variable nor in request.META.
In the IIS logs (The logs in C:\inetpub) I can see that it recognises my user, but IIS does not seem to forward that user information to the Django server. A line in the logs looks e.g. as follows:
2024-12-11 12:10:20 <SERVER IP> GET /<PATH> - <PORT> <DOMAIN>\<USERNAME> <CLIENT IP> <BROWSER DATA> ...
So, IIS clearly does perform Windows Authentication, and it works, but that information somehow never makes it to the Django server.
I have tried using Django's RemoteUserMiddleware, which does not change the behaviour.
Is there some additional setting that I am missing?

Note: If you follow the linked post you'll need to check the X-IIS-WindowsAuthToken header which would be present in request.META as HTTP_X_IIS_WINDOWSAUTHTOKEN

This is unfortunately not the case, there is no such object in request.META.

You have to set forwardWindowsAuthToken to true in your IIS configuration as the question states...
